# Reflect on y axis in 3D Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a question saying "Define a 3D Matrix that performs a reflection in the y axis" but I don't know how to solve it.

So if we have a 2D matrix and we say 'reflection on the y axis' we mean that x becomes -x. So a point (x,y) will be (-x, y).

But what about in 3D? If we are reflecting on y, are both x and z negated?

I tried to look for solutions and found this website http://www.idomaths.com/linear_transformation_3d.php on which I can see it's talking about xy, xz and yz planes.

Does 'reflect on the y axis' mean the same thing as 'reflect against the xz plane'?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question asks you to find a matrix representing a linear transformation $T$ that is only described geometrically, your task is to figure out how that $T$ transforms a *basis* for your domain.

Unfortunately I can't find a good image on Google Images to describe reflection through a line in $\Bbb R^3$ (and my `pgfplots`-fu is still pretty basic), but I'll try to describe what it means.  Consider an arbitrary point in $\Bbb R^3$.  Now connect that point to the $y$-axis by a line segment that is orthogonal to the $y$-axis.  Extend that line segment past $y$ by the same length as the distance from the point to the $y$-axis.  The far end of that line segment is then at the point that is the reflection of your point across the $y$-axis.

Let's see how this affects the standard basis $\{\hat x, \hat y, \hat z\}$.  $T(\hat x)$ goes back along the $x$-axis, goes through the $y$-axis at the origin, and then to $-\hat x$.  Thus $T(\hat x) = -\hat x$.  Likewise $T(\hat z) = -\hat z$.  $\hat y$ on the other hand is unaffected by this transformation -- it's its own reflection across the $y$-axis.

Thus, if $T(x) = Ax$ where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, then $$\begin{matrix}A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, & A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, & A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\end{matrix}$$

Therefore $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

---

The difference between reflecting through a line vs a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ is comparable to reflecting through the origin vs a line in $\Bbb R^2$.  Go back and look up the geometric properties of *even* and *odd* functions if you don't remember how these reflections work in $\Bbb R^2$ (note however that you can *still* reflect through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$).

Try to visualize each of these reflections in $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$.  Then consider how you think reflections would work in $\Bbb R^n$ for other values of $n$.

Comment: what does it mean to reflect on a line in three dimensions?

Comment: @abel I tried to explain what reflecting through a line in $\Bbb R^3$ means in my $2^{nd}$ paragraph (or at least one *specific* line, but the same technique applies to *any* line passing through the origin).

Comment: i understand that now. perhaps another way of seeing is to project onto the  $y$-axis and subtract the projection to get the normal component. that is $r = r_{\parallel} + r_\perp$ and $T(r) = r_{\parallel} - r_\perp.$

Comment: Mentally that's what I was describing, but I figured reflections probably come before projections in most linear algebra courses -- though I could be wrong.

Comment: no, you explained well(+1). i was just lazy to read through a whole paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

No, these mean two different things;

the reflection in the y-axis takes $(x,y,z)\to(-x,y,-z)$.

You can write down the matrix from this fact, and you can also get it

using $R=2P-I$, where $P$ is the matrix that projects each point onto the y-axis.